# How to show custom layout at the top of the MultiSelectListPreference

Tags: android

I want to create a custom MultiSelectListPreference with "Select All" feature on the top of the preference.
I tried the same by extending MultiSelectListPreference and setting the select all layout, but select all layout is coming at the bottom of the list preference as shown in attached image.

[image]

```
Here is code snippet -
```

1. Main preference file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <PreferenceCategory android:title="Interfaces">
            <com.samsung.trafficstats.settings.InterfacePreference
                android:defaultValue="@array/empty_array"
                android:dialogTitle="All Interfaces"
                android:key="all_interfaces"
                android:summary="show all interfaces" />
        </PreferenceCategory>
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

I am populating these entries and values at run time.

2. "select_all layout file" which I want to set at the top of the multiSelectPreference -

   ```
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="Select All"
       android:textSize="17sp" />

   <CheckBox
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />
   ```

3.Custom Preference file -

```
public class InterfacePreference extends MultiSelectListPreference{

    public InterfacePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.select_all_layout);
        setPositiveButtonText("save");
        setNegativeButtonText(android.R.string.cancel);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to show the "Select all" layout at the top of the list?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could edit the preference default layout. if you want a custom layout, you maybe should have to create whole layout page without using android preference and use ListView instead. Here is tutorial on how to create it [Multiple selection ListView with Custom Layout](http://adanware.blogspot.my/2012/04/android-multiple-selection-listview.html)